# Keeping track of read logs in java

Tags: java

I'm writing a small class which basically reads multiple logs and if there is an error in any of the logs to send me an email. I am doing a scan of the files every 5 minutes, and my problem is that I need to be able to keep track of the files already read, so I only get an email once if an error occurs.
The only way I can think of doing this at the moment is to update the log file with a keyword that if my application finds it won't email me, because the error message has been emailed to me.
If anybody can think of a better way to do this please I would appreciate your thoughts or comments.

Comment: What is the IO class you are using to read the files?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of polluting the data you are working on, i would like to keep the  read files metadata in cache  or store it in some persistent store . It may be some file or relational db.

Comment: I'm not sure how this would work. The log files I am reading from are produced by an application I have no control over and it creates separate logs for each process I need to run. 

If I get the files let's say on a 5 min interval and update the db with the content, I would still be populating the db with duplicated records.
The main thing I am struggling with is to determine if at any given time I have already checked any one of the log files and and email me only once.
Could you please elaborate on your answer if I misunderstood.

Thanks